# In rails, trying to make multiple substitutions but only the first one is taking

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4, search, replace, substitution

I’m trying to make multiple substitutions on a variable, whose value is

```
https://api.mydomein.com/events/EVENTID/profiles?max=10&total=1&appid=1234f5bf9f36bc4a1dc8fce2&token=9997aa817ff66b96f3956835f17941e1&search=4001&func=na&parms=%7B%22browser%22%3Afalse%7D&settings=%7B%22setWait%22%3Afalse%7D&_=1468271558064
```

and I attempt to make the substitutions this way …

```
  object_desc_link = OBJECT_DESC_LINK_TEMPLATE.sub( %r{events\/([^\\])+}, "events/#{@event_id}" )
                         .sub( %r{appid=([^\&])+}, "appid=#{@app_id}" )
                         .sub( %r{token=([^\&])+}, "token=#{@token}" )
                         .sub( %r{search=([^\&])+}, "search=#{i}" )
```

but after this statement is run the value is

```
https://api.mydomein.com/events/EVENTID
```

For some reason, the first substitutions is cutting off the last part of the URL.  How do I keep the entirety of the string and make substitutions in the places I specify them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed up your regex. Should be

```
%r{events/([^/])+}
```

You had `\\` in there. There are no backslashes in the path part of an url.

BTW, why don't you use a **proper** tool for the job? Parsing urls is a solved problem.

```
s = 'https://api.mydomein.com/events/EVENTID/profiles?max=10&total=1&appid=1234f5bf9f36bc4a1dc8fce2&token=9997aa817ff66b96f3956835f17941e1&search=4001&func=na&parms=%7B%22browser%22%3Afalse%7D&settings=%7B%22setWait%22%3Afalse%7D&_=1468271558064'

require "addressable/uri"
uri = Addressable::URI.parse(s)
h = uri.query_values # => {"max"=>"10", "total"=>"1", "appid"=>"1234f5bf9f36bc4a1dc8fce2", "token"=>"9997aa817ff66b96f3956835f17941e1", "search"=>"4001", "func"=>"na", "parms"=>"{\"browser\":false}", "settings"=>"{\"setWait\":false}", "_"=>"1468271558064"}

h['appid'] = 'whatever'
uri.query_values = h
uri.path = uri.path.sub('EVENTID', '42')

uri.to_s # => "https://api.mydomein.com/events/42/profiles?_=1468271558064&appid=whatever&func=na&max=10&parms=%7B%22browser%22%3Afalse%7D&search=4001&settings=%7B%22setWait%22%3Afalse%7D&token=9997aa817ff66b96f3956835f17941e1&total=1"
```